# Strange character render issue browsing Google/Youtube through Firefox/Chrome

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, firefox, browser, character-encoding

I am having issues in both Firefox and Chrome browser on Windows 10. When you browse to www.google.com it just render something like this (I took that img from Google Image not an actual screenshot but it looks exactly like this) [image]

This is happening with both Firefox and Chrome, but not happening with Microsoft Edge. Also is just happening with google.com or google.es and sometimes with youtube but other pages seem to work correctly.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling chrome or firefox?

Comment: I will try, but it's weird is happening in two different browsers and not in Edge

Comment: You need to show us an actual example from your system, along with the URL. All character jumbles are not created equally.

Comment: A friend of mine is seeing exact same problem on Windows 7. Updated Firefox to 56.0.2 and Chrome to 62.0.3202.89, but no fix. Rendering only seems screwed up on google.com & maps.google.com, other sites are OK.